# Start and stop Dropbox nightly with Mac

Tags: macos, backup, dropbox, cron

Dropbox is a beast and really slows down my computer. I've read that if I upgrade my account to a premium account, it will run faster, but I figure it would just be cool if I could automatically start and stop Dropbox on a nightly basis. How can I do this on a Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is an adaptation of the great posts at https://superuser.com/questions/648696/how-to-stop-and-start-dropbox-app-in-apple-terminal

(This example requires some technical knowhow)

```
$ crontab -e
```

Add the following to your crontab file and save:

```
# Start dropbox at 1 AM
0 1 * * * open -a "Dropbox"

# Stop dropbox at 5 AM
0 5 * * * osascript -e 'tell application "Dropbox" to quit'
```

Comment: what are some advantages to starting it at 1am and stopping it at 5am?

Comment: @Tri, this way, I can backup my files at night while I am not using my computer

Comment: oh I see. does it require your computer to be open at 1am? or does it work even if the Mac is in sleep mode?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, your computer must be on when dropbox starts or the backup won't work.